# Transparent change value of return value via ORM

Tags: php, oop, orm, model, kohana

I have ORM Model Hardware. And hardware has relationship to Type ORM model.
I need get option from Hardware model, for example:

```
$hardware->option
```

But if option is empty i want get option from type model:

```
$hardware->type->option
```

I want do it automatically (transparent) in hardware orm. I did:

```
public function __get($column) {

    if($column == 'option') {

        if ($this->option != null) {
            return $this->option;
        } else {
            // if option equals null then use value from type of this hardware
            return $this->type->captive_portal;
        }
    }

    return parent::__get($column);
}
```

But it's don't work. Because $this->option don't work because first i need call parent __get method for relationship work. But i can't call parent method __get and after it get true value. Or can?

Answer (score 1):

It's working good ;)

```
public function __get($column) {
    if($column == 'option') {
        return $this->getOption( parent::__get($column) );
    } else {
        return parent::__get($column);
    }
}

public function getOption($thisValue) {

    if ($thisValue != null) {
        return $thisValue;
    } else {
        // if option equals null then use value from type of this hardware
        return $this->type->option;
    }
}
```